# Upload SLD's graphic using geoserver's REST API

Tags: java, rest, geoserver, sld

How to upload SLD's graphic using geoserver's REST API.
I have managed to upload SLD's style file but I do not see any possibility to upload graphic which style is using.

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer's REST API does not support uploading images, unfortunately.  However, if you just set up an FTP service or something to allow you to upload to the styles/ directory you shoud not have any problems using them in uploaded SLDs.  There is an FTP extension available for GeoServer (see the [nightly builds](http://gridlock.opengeo.org/geoserver/2.0.x/community-latest/) of community modules) but it currently only allows uploads to the `data/` subdirectory.  Another possibility is to host the images via HTTP and access them via HTTP URLs in SLD.